# Why does Tortoise SVN's Revert Update Item to This Revision not work?

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn

I've had this happen a few times and previously assumed I was doing something wrong.
However, I actually re-read the manual and I'm doing it right.

1. I modified our normalize.css and fouled up something.
2. From the Tortoise Log, I did a Diff with the working copy and saw the previous checkin was correct.
3. I did a Revert to This Item (also tried Update Item to this Revision)
4. It claimes success but when I do a Diff again (or look at the working copy) it's still the fouled up one.

What I had to do (and did previously) is to *Save Revision as..." and use the working copy file name.  But that seems like a kluddge (and is extra steps)

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/eD9ByE08Vgf4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a `diff with working copy` from the top revision in the log dialog, and there actually is a difference. So that means that you have local modifications in your working copy, and those changes have not been committed yet.

Now, whatever you do now, Subversion will never ever lose those local modifications. Because that would mean that you could actually lose information. And SVN will never do that.

So, to make this work as you would expect, first commit your local modifications or revert them. After that, your `Revert to this revision` or even `Update to this revision` will work as you expect.